# Plotting several functions, each one with different properties using Table

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have these four different functions in the same plane:

```
    Plot[Evaluate[Table[Sqrt[2/Pi] Sin[(n Pi x)/Pi], {n, 4}]], {x, 0, Pi},
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "\[CapitalPhi]"}, 
    PlotLegend -> {"n = 1", "n = 2", "n = 3", "n = 4"}, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Dashed, Red},
    {Thick, DotDashed, Orange}, {Thick, Dashing[Large], Green}}]
```

Now I want to plot those four functions, each one in a different plane, preserving their unique properties. I tried something like:

```
    Table[Plot[Sqrt[2/Pi] Sin[(n Pi x)/Pi], {x, 0, Pi}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "\[CapitalPhi]"}], {n, 4}, 
    PlotLegend -> {"n = 1", "n = 2", "n = 3", "n = 4"}, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Dashed, Red},
    {Thick, DotDashed, Orange}, {Thick, Dashing[Large], Green}}]
```

but Mathematica tells me that it does not have the correct form of an iterator. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
lst = {Blue, {Dashed, Red}, {Orange, DotDashed}, {Green, 
    Dashing[Large]}};
Grid[{Table[
   Plot[Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] Sin[(n \[Pi] x)/\[Pi]], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "\[CapitalPhi]"}, ImageSize -> 250, 
    PlotLabel -> Row[{"n=", n}], PlotStyle -> {Thick, lst[[n]]}], {n, 
    4}]}]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: WOWWW!!! Thanks A LOT for this, bro! If you could explain me how does that "lst" work, you'll be my god from now. Please!

Comment: I've already figured out. You are defining a set called lst. The set can be defined as we wish. :)

Comment: I defined an auxiliary list: `lst = {Blue, {Orange, DotDashed}, {Green, Dashing[Large]}};`. Its first element is `lst[[1]]`. It is equal to `Blue`. The second element, `lst[[2]]` is `{Dashed, Red}` and so on. Therefore,  `PlotStyle -> {Thick, lst[[n]]}` for each element of the `Table` gives the desired style option.

Comment: Thank you. Have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

Using `GraphicsGrid`

```
GraphicsGrid[{
  Table[
   Plot[Sqrt[2/Pi] Sin[n Pi x/Pi], {x, 0, Pi},
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "p"},
    ImagePadding -> 2,
    PlotLabel -> Row[{"n=", n}],
    PlotRangePadding -> 0.15,
    PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][n]],
   {n, 4}]},
 ImageSize -> 800,
 Frame -> All,
 FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[0.8],
 Spacings -> Scaled[.2]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Table[Plot[Sqrt[2/Pi] Sin[(n Pi x)/Pi], {x, 0, Pi}, 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "\[CapitalPhi]"}, 
PlotLegends -> {"n = 1", "n = 2", "n = 3", "n = 4"}, 
PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Dashed, Red}, {Thick, 
DotDashed, Orange}, {Thick, Dashing[Large], Green}}], {n, 4}]
```

Comment: I've Mathematica ver.8.0, so PlotLegends is not supported :(
Thanks anyway, bro.